# Django Capturing multiple url parameters in request.GET

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

i am trying to get all query parameters out of an request

```
url/?animal__in=dog,cat&countries__in=france
```

I tried

```
animals = request.GET.get('animal__in','')
countries = request.GET.get('countries__in','')
```

but then animals and countries are not lists, they are just strings. Is there a more django way to do this whole capturing?

Edit:
Its important that i am using it in django-admin for filtering, where these two are not the same:

```
url/?animal__in=dog,cat&countries__in=france
url/?animal__in=dog&animal__in=cat&countries__in=france
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request.GET.getlist('some_list_field')

Answer (score 1):

Send the parameters in the proper HTTP format:

```
?animal__in=dog&animal__in=cat&countries__in=france
```

and do

```
request.GET.getlist('animal__in')
```

Comment: I want to use it as a filter in django-admin: So when i try this, it is the same like: ?animal__in=cat&countries__in=france

Answer (score 1):

split(',') works fine, not really django though

```
animals = request.GET.get('animal__in','').split(',')
countries = request.GET.get('countries__in','').split(',')
```